# NodeJS ES6: Class module exports

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6, module

Thank for read my topic, today, i have a quest about classes in es6, i don't why vi go error when i run.
I have class A:

```
var B = require("./b");
class A{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class A");
    }

    helloLoop() {
        console.log("A: Hello loop");
        B.hello();
    }

    helloWithoutLoop() {
        console.log("A: Hello without loop");
     }
}

module.exports = new A();
```

and class B:

```
var A = require("./a");
class B{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class B");
    }

    hello() {
        console.log("B: Hello");
        A.helloWithoutLoop();
    }
}

module.exports = new B();
```

and a test:

```
var A = require("./a");
var B = require("./b");

A.helloLoop();
```

When i run test, i receive a error:

```
A.helloWithoutLoop();
TypeError: A.helloWithoutLoop is not a function
at B.hello ({work-sapce}\test\b.js:9:11)
```

I don't that happen!
Please help me!
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  Your main file requires A which requires B which requires A (circular).  Can't do that.  The second attempt to require A before A itself has finished loading will return `null` which is why you get the weird error you do.

The usual solution is to find the common code and put it in a third module that both the others can load and not have A loading B and B loading A.

Have A loading C and B loading C.

Or, even simpler, just put A and B in the same file so there is no circular loading between them.

Comment: Thank you, i understood but when i put A and B in the same file, like testAB.js, and remove all require in another file, vi still error

Comment: I think about that and when i test again, i put require A or B (only) when i need in class A and B. And pumm, this run without error. Thank you very much

Comment: @KimEricko - I don't know what "vi still error" means.  If there's a run-time Javascript error, then you need to include both the exact code you're testing and the exact error message.  There's no way we can help debug without that info.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can call them :

```
import A from './A';
import B from './B';

A.helloLoop();
```

This is class A :

```
import B from './B';

class A{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class A");
    }

    helloLoop() {
        console.log("A: Hello loop");
        B.hello();
    }

    helloWithoutLoop() {
        console.log("A: Hello without loop");
     }
}

export default new A();
```

This is class B :

```
import A from './A';

class B{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class B");
    }

    hello() {
        console.log("B: Hello");
        A.helloWithoutLoop();
    }
}

export default new B();
```

see the difference ?

Comment: An answer with no explanation is like a detective mystery.  You don't explain what you changed and why and any reader has to try to figure that out.  You still have a circular dependency between A and B which is not a good design even if you might have found a hack that makes it work.

Comment: You are right.
I will explain my answer, I just wanted to give @kim a solution to his/her problem. 
I agree with u that both codes have circular dependency.